# CKEDITOR 4 get selected list items on a multiple list

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In my CKEDITOR 4 plugin, I have a select element with `multiple: true,` settings.

How can I get the selected elements?

`commit: function (data) {
   console.log(this.getValue());
}`

This one only return with the first selection.

Code part:

```
{
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Role list',
    id: 'role',
    label: 'Role list',
    multiple: true,
    controlStyle: 'min-height: 10em;width:100%;',
    style: 'min-height: 10em;width: 100%;',
    items: roleListJSON,
    setup: function (data) {
        //todo: setup selection from data.roles
    },
    commit: function (data) {
        var selected_values = this.getValue();  //its wrong

    }
}
```

Comment: I try this.getValues(), but not working. What is the magic function? : )

Comment: One solution is using Jquery:  var selected_values = $(this.getInputElement().$).val();  But there must be a ckeditor compatible method :)